# Grails Criteria, order by month and only in current year of a date

Tags: groovy, grails, criteria

I am currently trying to change this query so that it only returns items sorted by month then manufacturer, and are only in this year.

```
List<Item> results = criteria.list {
            resultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AnalyticsCredits))

            // Select columns
            projections {
                product {
                    mfg {
                        groupProperty(Constants.NAME, GROUP_LABEL)
                    }
                }

                sum(ANTICIPATED_CREDIT, TOTAL_CREDITS)
                count(WARRANTY_CLAIM, NUMBER_OF_CLAIMS)

            }

            // Where conditions
            anticipatedCreditEligible(delegate)
            if (analyticsCmd.facilityHospital) {
                warrantyCase {
                    eq(FACILITY_HOSPITAL, analyticsCmd.facilityHospital)
                }
            } else {
                warrantyCase {
                    'in'(FACILITY_HOSPITAL, user.userHospitals)
                }
            }

            int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
            // Filter by the extracted year
            // eq("dateCreated", currentYear) -> does not work
            // Group by month
            // groupProperty("dateCreated.month") -> does not work
        }

        return results
```

I didn't really expect the ways I tried to work but I cannot figure out how else to accomplish this. Please let me know.

I tried to create a projection but was unable to do so successfully.

Comment: Can also post your domain definition for reference, it will be good for problem resolution